# HTML form radio buttons to execute bash script using php.

Tags: php, html, bash

I am trying to execute a bash script on my server from a radio button and submit button on my web page. There are two radio buttons and each will execute a different bash script (test1.sh test2.sh). Here is what i have so far.

Webpage HTML:

```
<form action="testexec.php" method="get">
<label class="col">Up/Down</label>
<span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
  <label for="r1">Up</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
  <label for="r2">Down</label>
</span>
<span class="col">
  <input type="submit" />
</span>
```

test1.sh/test2.sh (/var/www/html/testscripts)

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/testfile
ls -ltr /tmp
```

testexec.php (same directory as my web page)

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/testscript/test.sh");
header('Location: http://psat/moslehpour/dadt/main/systemTest.php?
success=true');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"
?>
```

When click the submit button I do not see any action on my server side. Also, how can I verify something is happening, I tried to echo out to the webpage but nothing seems to show.

Comment: If you want to see your output, you need to remove the redirect

Comment: you also named your input fields both "option", this will just send option=2. You have to change it to option[] and in your php-script $_GET[option][0], $_GET[option][1] to get the values or just name them diefferently

Comment: @MarouenMhiri When I set the options to option1 and option2, it will allow me to select both radio buttons. how can I set the options to only allow the user to select one option?

Comment: Oh okay! in your case you cannot name theme differently because they belong to same "group" so just only use name="options[]" und you can get each value using $_GET['options][0] or $_GET['options'][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
 <form action="testexec.php" method="POST">
  <label class="col">Up/Down</label>
   <span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" >test1
  <label for="r1">Up</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" >test2
  <label for="r2">Down</label>
 </span>
 <span class="col">
<input type="submit" />
```

```
 <?php
 //when the submit button is clicked
 if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

 //name the radio 1 option1
 if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 'test1' )
 { $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/testscript/test.sh");}

 //name the radio 2 option1
 if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 'test2')
 { $output = shell_exec("/var/www/html/testscript/test.sh");}

 //remove  this  if you want to see $output in this file
 header('Location: http://psat/moslehpour/dadt/main/systemTest.php?
 success=true');

 echo "<pre>$output</pre>"
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Do I have to change the method to POST in my html page?

Comment: Also why do you prefer POST over GET?

Comment: @kkmoslehpour 2)I don't prefer get over post or vice versa... if the data is sensible i prefer post method... so that the user can't manipulate the url... In general, I prefer sending data with POST..

Comment: Okay, thank you. One last thing before I +1, When I set the options to option1 and option2, it will allow the user to select both radio buttons. how can I set the options to only allow the user to select one option and do things based on that option?

Comment: Nice, that did it! when you put test1 and test2 outside of the input brackets does it label it as test1 and test2?